# Cannot read property 'click' of undefined while using Java Script Executor in Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am getting an error:

```
Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
```

while trying to click a button using java script executor. I have tried many different approach to click the button using action classes, webdriverwait etc but none seems to work.Java Script is working in console but when i am using in my code i am unable to click the button and getting the mentioned error

The html dom looks as below:

```
<div>
    <a class="button button--new-resource" href="/admin/certificate_types/new">
        <img src="/assets/icon-add-user-e2a98953aa1855b15304eb16415b536ee92e579ce89f429bcdd062faa855e261.svg" alt="Icon add user"> New Certificate Type
    </a>
</div>
```

My selenium script is as below

```
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;        
js.executeScript("var x= document.getElementsByClassName('button button--new-resource')[0];"+"x.click();");
```

Comment: Why are you using a javascript executor instead of findElements and the click() method?

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
```

...implies that the `click()` method can't be executed as the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) haven't completely rendered within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) and the element is still in **undefined** state.

---

### Details

As you mentioned that the *"Java Script is working in console"* that implies the *JavaScript* is perfecto. The main issue is the element haven't rendered completely within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

---

### Solution

As a solution, you need to induce you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector(".button.button--new-resource")));
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("var x= document.getElementsByClassName('button button--new-resource')[0];"+"x.click();");
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//*[@class='button button--new-resource']")));
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("var x= document.getElementsByClassName('button button--new-resource')[0];"+"x.click();");
  ```

---

### Best practices

However, as per best practices to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.button.button--new-resource[href='/admin/certificate_types/new']>img[alt='Icon add user']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='button button--new-resource' and @href='/admin/certificate_types/new']/img[@alt='Icon add user']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong way to pass element into the JSExecutor, you need to combine it with FindElement call. In your case, the script might be executed before the element can be found, resulting 'undefined' error.

```
// find the element
var element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@class='button button--new-resource']")));

// execute the click on the element you have found
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in quotation marks

```
js.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('button button--new-resource')[0].click();");
```

should do the job

if there is only one button

`<a class="button button--new-resource" href="/admin/certificate_types/new">`

use `document.getElementByClassName` and do not use index:

`js.executeScript("document.getElementByClassName('button button--new-resource').click();");`

Comment: The second one is throwing syntax error and first one isnt working

Comment: Do you necessary find the element using js? Why not using: WebElement element = driver.findElement(By. ... ?

Answer (score 0):

your locator is wrong , its a multi class element use '.' instead of space

```
js.executeScript("var x= document.getElementsByClassName('button.button--new-resource')[0];"+"x.click();");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use js executor? Try

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className(CLASS_NAME));
element.click();
```