# JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined error executing JavaScript through Python Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have the following code in which I enter a page and search for a product, I want to execute a JavaScript code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
#-------------------------------------------PRODUCT SEARCH-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\stbaz\\Documents\\Python\\ChromeTools\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
driver.get("https://www.innvictus.com/")
product_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("is-navigation__search-bar__input")
product_textbox.send_keys("FW7093")
product_textbox.submit()
#------------------------------------------PRODUCT SEARCH END--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

driver.implicitly_wait(5)
js='javascript:document.getElementsByClassName("buy-button buy-button--sticky buy-button--buy-now visible-xs visible-sm")[1].click();window.open("/checkout")'
driver.execute_script(js)
```

But I get the following error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
```

I can run that code manually in chrome, I use a bookmark, but I want to run it in Python, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Manually accessing the url shows `Error 1009` **Access denied**

Comment: Which button you would like to click?

Comment: Also, re `product_textbox.submit()`. You submit a `form` not an `input` element.

Comment: Its no a button, I run that script, using a chorme bookmark and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Mainly Getting an error "Cannot read property 'click' of undefined" is if selector or class cannot be found in the DOM. I believe the error happens if JavaScript cannot find the selector in the markup/DOM or if it does not exist.
Maybe you should try
`js='javascript:document.getElementsByClassName("buy-button buy-button--sticky  buy-button--buy-now visible-xs visible-sm").click();window.open("/checkout")'`
with out the index.
check [Cannot read property 'click' of undefined while using Java Script Executor in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514947/cannot-read-property-click-of-undefined-while-using-java-script-executor-in-se)
It may help

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
```

...implies that the `click()` method can't be executed as the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) haven't completely rendered within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) and the element is still an **undefined** element.

---

### Solution

To execute the JavaScript, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".buy-button.buy-button--sticky.buy-button--buy-now.visible-xs.visible-sm")))
  driver.execute_script("var x= document.getElementsByClassName('buy-button buy-button--sticky buy-button--buy-now visible-xs visible-sm')[0];"+"x.click();")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='buy-button buy-button--sticky buy-button--buy-now visible-xs visible-sm']")))
  driver.execute_script("var x= document.getElementsByClassName('buy-button buy-button--sticky buy-button--buy-now visible-xs visible-sm')[0];"+"x.click();")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Now I have this  selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Can you update the question with the relevant HTML?

Comment: The problem its that there is not a specific html code, my JavaScript code works when I use it as a bookmark on chrome, and it works when i click on it, for example https://www.innvictus.com/hombres/basket/tenis/nike/tenis-nike-kyrie-7-black-white/p/000000000000175791 use this link, and the JavaScript should send you to checkout

Comment: Ummm, I still see _...The owner of this website (www.innvictus.com) has banned the country or region your IP address is in (IN) from accessing this website...._

Answer (score 0):

So, I included the main program without using `JavaScript`; but, under the Main Program Reference, I included the method for using `JavaScript` as well.

To achieve this solution without JS, I used `xpath` to validate that the page loaded successfully. Then, after that, I found the `xpath` for the search button

```
//nav[@class='is-navigation']//span[contains(@class, 'search-btn')]
```

Once I discovered the `xpath` for this, I clicked the search button and then I created a method to search for a specific product. In my example, I used the "Converse" shoes as an example.

```
def search_for_text(driver : ChromeDriver, text : str):
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//form[@id='formSearch']//input[contains(@data-options, 'SearchBox')]").send_keys(text)
    time.sleep(2)
    if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//form[@id='formSearch']//input[contains(@data-options, 'SearchBox')]").get_attribute('value').__len__() != text.__len__():
        raise Exception("Failed to populate our search textbox")
    else:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//form[@id='formSearch']//input[contains(@data-options, 'SearchBox')]").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(2)
        wait_displayed(driver, "//div[@class='is-pw__products']//div[contains(@class, 'products-list')]", 30)
        print(f'Your search for {text} was successful')
```

In that method, you see that I used `wait_displayed` to validate that my product list displays properly.

**MAIN PROGRAM - FOR REFERENCE**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver as ChromeDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as DriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as DriverConditions
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


def get_chrome_driver():
    """This sets up our Chrome Driver and returns it as an object"""
    path_to_chrome = "F:\Selenium_Drivers\Windows_Chrome87_Driver\chromedriver.exe"
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    
    # Browser is displayed in a custom window size
    chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1500,1000")
    
    return webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chrome,
                            options = chrome_options)

    
def wait_displayed(driver : ChromeDriver, xpath: str, int = 5):
    try:
         DriverWait(driver, int).until(
            DriverConditions.presence_of_element_located(locator = (By.XPATH, xpath))
        )
    except:
        raise WebDriverException(f'Timeout: Failed to find {xpath}')
    
    
def is_displayed(driver : ChromeDriver, xpath: str, int = 5):
    try:
         webElement = DriverWait(driver, int).until(
            DriverConditions.presence_of_element_located(locator = (By.XPATH, xpath))
        )
         return True if webElement != None else False
    except:
        return False
    
    
def click_search(driver : ChromeDriver):
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//nav[@class='is-navigation']//span[contains(@class, 'search-btn')]").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    if is_displayed(driver, "//form[@id='formSearch']//input[contains(@data-options, 'SearchBox')]") == False:
        raise Exception("Failed to click our search button")
    else:
        print('You clicked the Search Button Successfully')
    
    
def search_for_text(driver : ChromeDriver, text : str):
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//form[@id='formSearch']//input[contains(@data-options, 'SearchBox')]").send_keys(text)
    time.sleep(2)
    if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//form[@id='formSearch']//input[contains(@data-options, 'SearchBox')]").get_attribute('value').__len__() != text.__len__():
        raise Exception("Failed to populate our search textbox")
    else:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//form[@id='formSearch']//input[contains(@data-options, 'SearchBox')]").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(2)
        wait_displayed(driver, "//div[@class='is-pw__products']//div[contains(@class, 'products-list')]", 30)
        print(f'Your search for {text} was successful')
        


# Gets our chrome driver and opens our site
chrome_driver = get_chrome_driver()
chrome_driver.get("https://www.innvictus.com/")
wait_displayed(chrome_driver, "(//nav[@class='is-navigation']//div[contains(@class, 'desktop-menu')]//a[contains(@href, 'lanzamientos')])[1]")
wait_displayed(chrome_driver, "//div[@class='content-page']//div[@class='scrolling-wrapper-flexbox']")
wait_displayed(chrome_driver, "//nav[@class='is-navigation']//span[contains(@class, 'search-btn')]")
click_search(chrome_driver)
search_for_text(chrome_driver, "Converse")
chrome_driver.quit()
chrome_driver.service.stop()
```

**COMMAND FOR CLICKING THE SEARCH BUTTON USING JAVASCRIPT**

```
jsText = "document.querySelector('nav').querySelector('div .is-navigation__main').querySelector('div .is-navigation__main__right').querySelector('span').click()"
driver.execute_script(jsText)
```

**METHOD**

```
def click_search_using_javaScript(driver : ChromeDriver):
    jsText = "document.querySelector('nav').querySelector('div .is-navigation__main').querySelector('div .is-navigation__main__right').querySelector('span').click()"
    driver.execute_script(jsText)
    time.sleep(2)
    if is_displayed(driver, "//form[@id='formSearch']//input[contains(@data-options, 'SearchBox')]") == False:
        raise Exception("Failed to click our search button")
    else:
        print('You clicked the Search Button Successfully')
```